# PHPMailer not sending all emails to last email address

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send emails. I have created a function that sends 3 emails to 3 different email addresses (sending 9 emails in total).

- The first email address is receiving all the 3 emails.
- The second email address is receiving 2 emails.
- The third email address is receiving only 1 email.

Why this happening?

Here is my code:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'lib/phpmailer/vendor/autoload.php'; 

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail1 = phpmaileremail($reciever1, $usertype1, $file, $subject1, $body1);
$mail2 = phpmaileremail($reciever2, $usertype2, $file, $subject2, $body2);
$mail3 = phpmaileremail($reciever3, $usertype3, $file, $subject3, $body3);

function phpmaileremail($reciever,$usertype, $file, $subject, $body)
{
    global $mail;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                        
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'xxx@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'xxx';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                               
    $mail->Port = 587;   

    $mail->setFrom('xxx', 'xxx');            
    $mail->addAddress($reciever); 
    $mail->addAddress($reciever, $usertype); 

    $mail->addAttachment($file);

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                   
    $mail->Subject = $subject; 
    $mail->Body = $body; 
    $mail->AltBody = 'NA'; 
    $mail->send();

    echo "Mail sent";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're reusing the `$mail` object to `addAddress()` and `send()`. So the first time you call `phpmaileremail()` the first address gets the email. Then when you call it for the second time the second address is added and the first and second address get the email. And so on.

A simple solution would be to create the `$mail` object inside the `phpmaileremail()` function:

```
function phpmaileremail($reciever,$usertype, $file, $emailsubject, $email_body )
{

  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

  $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                        
  $mail->isSMTP();                                             
  $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com;';                     
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                              
  $mail->Username   = 'XXXXXXXX@gmail.com';                  
  $mail->Password   = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';                         
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                               
  $mail->Port       = 587;   

  $mail->setFrom('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX');            
  $mail->addAddress($reciever); 
  $mail->addAddress($reciever, $usertype); 
  // Attachments
  $mail->addAttachment($file);         // Add attachments

  $mail->isHTML(true);                                   
  $mail->Subject = $emailsubject; 
  $mail->Body    = $email_body; 
  $mail->AltBody = 'NA'; 
  $mail->send(); 

  echo "Mail sent"; 

}
```

PS: Not that it matters, but `reciever` is written `receiver`. I've made that mistake as well.

Answer (score 1):

Kiko's answer will work, however it's not the best way. As its name suggests, `addAddress` **adds** an address, it doesn't set absolutely or replace existing recipients you've already added.

PHPMailer has a standard function to clear the list of addresses you're ending to called `clearAddresses`, so the right approach is to call that after each message you send and add the new address before sending the next one, so the sequence will be roughly:

```php
addAddress();
send();
clearAddresses();
addAddress();
send();
```

and so on. This is most clearly demonstrated in [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps), which does its sending in a loop, calling `clearAddresses` each time around.

You can achieve the same thing using a new instance of PHPMailer each time (which has the effect of clearing addresses, but also clears everything else too), but it's more efficient to re-use the instance. This is especially true if you're sending over SMTP (which you are) because it will allow you to make use of keepalive, which dramatically reduces the overhead of making an SMTP connection. If you use a new instance, the connection is dropped and recreated each time. You can achieve this inside your function by making the PHPMailer instance static:

```
function phpmaileremail($reciever, $usertype, $file, $emailsubject, $email_body)
{
    static $mail;

    if ($mail === null) {
        //Set everything that remains the same all the time in here
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com;';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'XXXXXXXX@gmail.com';
        $mail->Password = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
        $mail->setFrom('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
    }
    $mail->addAddress($reciever, $usertype);
    // Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment($file);         // Add attachments

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $emailsubject;
    $mail->Body = $email_body;
    $mail->AltBody = 'NA';
    $mail->send();
    $mail->clearAddresses();
    $mail->clearAttachments();
    echo "Mail sent";
}
```

This has the added benefit of not using a global. Also note the use of `clearAttachments`, as that works the same way as addresses.

Comment: I agree that this is more efficient. Another, and slightly more standard way, to do this, would be to have two functions. The first function creates the connection to the mail server and returns the PHPMailer object. The second function will then use this object to send an email and return true on success or false on failure. This will keep the functions smaller as well, and they perform a single task, not multiple.

Comment: A better way of doing that is to subclass PHPMailer and configure your connection settings in that subclass.